# Writing 2 for loops by .map() function in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, .map

I would like to calculate the annual Hansen loss for different elevation classes.
I want to write a function that gives me a list holding 18 years of loss per elevation class.
I have written the following lines:

```
var loss = function(i) {
  var losscalculate = ee.Image(i) //for each year
    .updateMask(elclasses.get(k)) //for each elevation class
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: peru,
      scale:30,
      maxPixels:1e9,
      bestEffort: true });
    return losscalculate ;
};
```

Here I am struggling with writing a proper .map() line. Is there any way to use two variables in a .map() function. Or do you have any suggestion for me to write a 2 loops function?

Comment: I hope this helps you as reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47102922/double-loop-with-map-function-in-google-earth-engine

Comment: @aldo_tapia thank you! It worked!